# navigator.camera.getPicture not working in android after MFP iFIX - 7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201703011645

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

We are using Cordova camera plugin in our project. It was working fine before applying iFix - 7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201703011645.

Please check below code snippet for camera.

```
$scope.cameraOptions = {
                        quality: 50,
                        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                        sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
                     };

navigator.camera.getPicture( success , failure , $scope.cameraOptions );
```

Android Error logs:

```
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129): Uncaught exception from plugin
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129):     at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:560)
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129):     at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:534)
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129):     at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:376)
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129):     at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.takePicture(CameraLauncher.java:278)
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129):     at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.callTakePicture(CameraLauncher.java:258)
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129):     at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.execute(CameraLauncher.java:167)
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:86)
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:153)
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:61)
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129):     at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:40)
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129):     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129):     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:41)
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-21 20:36:41.990: E/PluginManager(29129):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
03-21 20:36:41.997: I/chromium(29129): [INFO:CONSOLE(204)] "Failed because: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference", source:
```

Comment: Note that requesting urgency here with get you some well-deserved downvotes - don't do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary workaround, please add the below lines of code to your AndroidManifest.xml within the application tag :

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

Comment: The related blog can be found here - https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/02/14/cordova-plugin-camera-fix-for-android-n/

Comment: Thank you so much Keerthi.. its working.. did changes in AndroidManifest.xml and config.xml

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue. Please open a PMR with IBM MobileFirst to receive the fix.